# Leading zero toString not working?

Tags: javascript, tostring

I am Beginner and i am doing the 6. exercise on https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-array-exercises.php

The thing that confuses me is that number has leading 0. This means input is 025468. If i use toString() method it returns string of "25468", .length is also ignoring 0. But as i see, if i prompt() and enter 025468, toString() than displays 0. Why is that? Why with prompt toString works and with variable set to number does not?

Answer (score 2):

> Why with prompt toString works and with variable set to number does
>   not?

because `prompt` already returns `string` so basically you are doing `"025468".toString()`, while for a `number` `025468` leading 0 is not significant.

**Demo**

```js
var str = "025468";
console.log( "String to String" , str.toString() );

var num = 025468;
console.log( "num as is " , num ); //leading 0 already removed
console.log( "num to String " , num.toString() );
```

Comment: The thing i do not get (confuses me) is, why would toString() remove leading 0? I mean, you are converting it to string, not number. I would get it if you would convert string to integer, to remove leading 0.
As for prompt, thank you, for explaining, makes sense.

Comment: Actually, the demo shows that leading 0 is removed before toString happened.